# Get iPhone Date and Time Settings in Swift

Tags: iphone, swift

How can I get iPhone's Date and Time Setting in Swift? I need to know if `automatic` is true and take specific action inside app.

[image: iPhone's Date and Time configuration in portuguese]

Comment: Why do you need to know? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @rmaddy I need to know if it's on automatic so I can trust the date and time user sends to the server, cause we had some cases user had changed date and time to fake it. I can't simply use server date and time because we have users in different countries with different timezones.

Comment: I really don’t think it’s a good idea to depend on the user to send the time to the server it should always be on the server side but if you insist then you can use https://github.com/instacart/TrueTime.swift

Comment: @zombie Does it get real time even if user fake date and time?

Comment: Read the readme it says it gets the time from a server

Comment: @EdsonHoracioJunior You do want to use the server time (in UTC). It doesn't matter what timezone the user is in. You can display the UTC timestamps in the user's current timezone when needed. There is no need to send the time from the device to the server unless you want to do some sort of verification that the user's clock is set correctly.

Comment: @zombie There's no need for such a library in this case. The "real" time that gets from an NTP server will be the same time the OP's own server will have.

Comment: True but But just Incase the time is needed to be displayed on the device. it’s already done

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't thing that's possible, but you can [get notified](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1414255-nssystemclockdidchange) when the user changes the date and time.